# Restarting remotely a PC with encrypted drive

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, disk-encryption

I've got a remote PC which I'm connecting to over the Internet. The PC has an encrypted drive. When I power it on, it first asks for a password to unlock the drive. If I've logged into it remotely and want to reboot it, is there a way to enter the password? Do I need to install some sort of management interface for this?

Comment: We cannot answer this question well until you give us more information. What OS? What sort of encryption? How are you supposed to access it? Is this a business computer? Have you spoken with the system administrators?

Answer (score 2):

If the computer's using a server-grade hardware, you could connect to it using BMC or IPMI (assuming it's configured) and enter the password. These features are provided by hardware itself, so they're available before the OS boots.

Intel AMT is a similar feature more widely available in consumer hardware. It's available in some of Intel's vPro-capable CPUs.

If you don't have this kind of hardware, you can run SSH from the early userspace to connect before the OS boots completely and unlock the disk by entering a password over remote console. In Debian and Ubuntu this feature is provided via the `dropbear-initramfs` package. [This guide](https://www.arminpech.de/2019/12/23/debian-unlock-luks-root-partition-remotely-by-ssh-using-dropbear/) is pretty complete, but very concise. Here's [another one](https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/) which is more detailed, but has some inaccuracies. Notes:

- **Don't configure this without physical access to the machine.** It's easy to miss a step and get stuck.
- LVM or lack of it isn't actually relevant.
- Instead of editing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/ip` an `ip=` param can be added in GRUB config (`/etc/default/grub`).
- You can set kernel IP param to `ip=dhcp` instead of static IP (remember to set IP reservation for DHCP server, because you'll have to SSH into this IP).
- Remember to `sudo update-grub` after editing GRUB config template.
- You can use Dropbear's `-c` command instead of `command=` in `authorized_keys`.